# Trigger Lambda/ Notify with SNS when a team member deploys APIG to particular stage

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, monitoring

I have an API Gateway with dev, qa, staging and prod deployment stages. I am trying to monitor these stages. Like if anyone intentionally or accidentally modifies any stage, send an email. 
Trying to trigger a lambda or notify via SNS topic.

Tried AWS Config, Cloudwatch monitoring. couldn't make it work. any help is appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AWS config solutions should work. I went on and checked on the console. A new deployment is shown as change in configuration for API gateway.

```
Amazon Resource Name arn:aws:apigateway:...

Resource type AWS::ApiGateway::Stage
```

[image]

I am also able to match that event in CloudWatch and trigger a Lambad function / SNS topic

[image]

Comment: Thanks @qkhanhpro. I will try this with Config. Meanwhile I debugged Cloudwatch Rule and got it fixed. there was an issue with the rule configuration.